# How to insert multiple values to database table using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, codeigniter

Plz check this jsfiddle. My results are like this,

http://jsfiddle.net/kz1vfnx2/

i need to store these datas to database(sql server) one by one in each row using PHP Codeigniter. Insert to table looks like

```
   Date           Frequency
05-Feb-2019   1st Basic Treatment
12-Mar-2019   2nd Control Treatment
----------------------------------
--------------------------------
```

when button clicks call the function and insert to datatabase

```
    $('#saveactivityarea').on('click', function(event) { //save new activity area
    var act_contractbranch_firstjobdt = "2019-01-01";
    var Contractend_firstjobdt = "2020-01-01";
    var act_job_freq_daysbtw= "30";
    saveschedule(act_contractbranch_firstjobdt,Contractend_firstjobdt,act_job_freq_daysbtw,0);

var contractID = $('#contractID').val();
var act_job_freq_contract = $("#act_job_freq_contract option:selected").val();
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'activity_submitted',
          data: {
            //here i need to pass date and frequency. insert to table like one by one row
            getcontract_id: contractID,
            getcontractbranch_firstjobdt: act_contractbranch_firstjobdt,
            //etc....

          }, 
          success: function(data) {
          alert('success')
}

    })
```

**PHP MODAL FUNCTION**

```
$data_jobschedule = array(
            'Contract_id' => $this->input->post('getcontract_id'),
            'job_freq_id' => $this->input->post('getcontractbranch_freq')
        );
$insert_id = 0;
        if ($this->db->insert("job_schedule", $data_jobschedule))
            $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @MuhammedShihabudeenLabbaA plz  check fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/kz1vfnx2/

Comment: when clicking the button, am calling a function it returns those results like in the fiddle..I want to pass these results in AJAX and insert into datatabse..

Answer (score 0):

Please find the jQuery Ajax code here
Inside while loop

```
var dataArray = [];
while(condition) {
   details = [];
   //do your calculations
   details['date'] = date;
   details['frequency'] = frequency;
   dataArray[] = details;
}

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('activity_submitted'); ?>",
    data: {dateArray: dataArray},
    success: function(data){
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function() { alert("Error."); }


    });
```

In the controller and model, you need to get the data and insert it into the table.

```
$data = $_REQUEST['dateArray'];
$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: i need to pass these values through ajax

Comment: @numukisdf, please check whether this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: i need to pass saveschedule() this function returns values to datatabse..in your code ur mention some form serialize..sorry i dont need this

Comment: am calling a function saveschedule() this results am showing in jsfiddle..then all the   dates i need to pass like an array through  ajax to codeigniter  controller function

Comment: @numukisdf, see the answer now. Added a jquery array and pass that using Ajax

Comment: how can i store ['date', 'frequencyString']; in variable dataArray ????

Comment: in database table two columns are there for date and frequency string

Comment: For array in jquery, read this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: if function returns 5 rows, i need to insert these rows and database table will be 5rows

Comment: that i know,but i dont know how i will access from the function

Comment: i didnt  get this var dataArray = ['date', 'frequencyString']; //get your data here in this array..how can i pass these all the two columns here?i dont understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198443/discussion-between-muhammed-shihabudeen-labba-a-and-numuki-sdf).